# Get the values of cells in the A column if the values of cells in the F column are less than a number

Tags: excel

[image]

I want to print min value in column A where cost per event < $470 (column F) & value of cells in the E column is 1.

This is what I've tried, but there are some syntax errors:

=MIN((A4:A38)IF(F4:F38),"<470" &(E4:E38>0)))

=IF(F3:F38), "<470" & IF(E3:E38), ">0", MIN(A4:A38).

The F column has been formatted to display a number, not a currency (after I took the screenshot)

If you know the correct syntax for this query, please answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MIN(IF((E4:E38=1)*(F4:F38<470),A4:A38))
```

**Note**: Commit this formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.